# Cabal install complains "<built-in>:0:4: lexical error (UTF-8 decoding error)"

Tags: haskell, windows-7, utf-8, cabal

I am using Windows 7 with locale zh_CN and ghc-7.0.4

Default code page of the cmd.exe is 936.

```
> cabal install ghc-mod
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring ghc-syb-utils-0.2.1.0...
Preprocessing library ghc-syb-utils-0.2.1.0...
Building ghc-syb-utils-0.2.1.0...

<built-in>:0:4: lexical error (UTF-8 decoding error)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghc-mod-1.10.7 depends on ghc-syb-utils-0.2.1.0 which failed to install.
ghc-syb-utils-0.2.1.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

I have tried change code page and re-install again, but get the same output.

```
> chcp 65001
> cabal install ghc-mod
```

Some packages can be built successfully:

`xml-1.3.12` `textmath-0.6.0.3` `tagsoup-0.12.6`

Some packages would fail:

`temporary-1.1.2.3` `utf8-string-0.3.7` `pandoc-types-1.9.0.2` `json-0.5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered the same problem.
I don't know if the cause is the same, but try

```
set LANG=C
```

before you run cabal. In my case, that fixed the problem.

Comment: Worked for me when I had similar `UTF-8 decoding error` but what exactly does setting that var do?